# Functional Dependency Rules

Tags: functional-dependencies

Given the following functional dependencies: **ABD -> C** and **C -> B**

is that then enough to say that **AD -> C**?

The rationale being that you would get **ABD -> CB**, and then **B** can be removed from both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A+ = {A}
B+ = {B}
C+ = {B,C}   
D+ = {D}
AD+ = {A,D}
```

You cannot remove them from both sides,just like you cannot remove C from both sides in **C+** shown above.
So the answer is that those two FDs are not sufficient to say that **AD->C**